# How to setup Uno + xbee shield 1.1 + wee wifi chip?

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee, web-service

I am an absolute beginner with electronics and Arduino.
I have this hardware:

- arduino uno
- xbee shield 1.1
- wee wifi chip

I've tried to make them work (to connect my Uno to the Internet) but I can't find the right tutorial.

Are there good resources I should look at, or do you know how set this up?

Answer (score 2):

As far as the Wi-Fi and Uno is concerned, it's not too difficult. You should download its library for Arduino, which is available on Github and then try its example named *Wifi Client*.

In this example, change your SSID and password, and run serial terminal. It will show you that your Arduino is connected to Wi-Fi and it will also display your IP Address.

Now enter this IP address in your browser and it's like you are pinging your Wi-Fi shield.  Soon it will display your analog values. Just make sure your computer and your Wi-Fi chip are connected to the same Wi-Fi connections.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try to make it work but I am such a noob that I would need a step by step tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking this in small hunks. If you haven't done it already, your first step should be to get your development environment together. Use it to create and upload a simple test. The Blink sketch is a common place to start. There are excellent tutorials at the Adafruit site, the have a whole series for [getting started with the Arduino](https://learn.adafruit.com/lesson-0-getting-started/overview).

After you've gotten far enough with the basics to start feeling confident. Try searching for a tutorial for your project. You can often find them by searching on Google – try something like "arduino xbee shield tutorial" – look for descriptions that sound like what you want to do and try reading them. Another good place to look for tutorials is on sites that sell the hardware you're interested in using. For example Adafruit has [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/xbee-radios/overview) on getting started with the Xbee.

As you work through the tutorials, come back with more questions. As you get more experience it will be easier to ask specific questions and those are easier to answer :-)